# PDF name adding to the table but not store into the folder

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I am using the below code to insert images and pdf names into the database. I am getting the issue with PDF and PPT.

I am getting the below errors while uploading the pdf and ppt. PDF name is adding into the table but not in the folder.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
     if(isset($_FILES['file1']['name']) && $_FILES['file1']['name'] != ""){
          $upload1=imagerename($_FILES['file1'], $pdo);
     } else{
          if (isset($_POST['file1']) && $_POST['file1']!= "") {
              $upload1=$_POST['file1'];
          } else{
              $upload1="";
          }
      }
      //$upload1=imagerename($_FILES['file1'], $pdo);
     $data=array(
        'upload1'=>$upload1,
     );
     $sql="UPDATE `upload` SET `upload1`=:upload1 WHERE id=1";
     $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute($data);
     echo"successfully updated";
}

function imagerename($image,$pdo){
    $image1  = $image['name'];
    $filename  = basename($image1);
    $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file        = mt_rand();// random number 
    $newname       = $file.'.'.$extension;
    $location='images/uploads/'.$newname;
    compressImage($image['tmp_name'],$location,60);
    return $newname;
}

// Compress image
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source); 
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
}
```

Comment: As a pdf and a ppt are not images your compressImage() function makes no sence

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes, I don't know how to handle this issue?. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Well first you have to decide what you want to do with things that are not images

Comment: @RiggsFolly, While uploading. Do I need to check the extension of the file? and according to extension, I have to call another function?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I simply save it in my folder. If Image then compress and PDF or PPT then store in folder

Comment: That sounds about right

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Is this correct logic? if ($extension=='png' || $extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg') {
    compressImage($image['tmp_name'],$location,60);
}
else{
  move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $location)
}

Comment: Its correct if it works

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Let me try this

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Yes, it's working. Do I need to optimize the pdf or ppt?

Comment: I have no idea how you would do that, so I cannot answer that question

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I was just asking for optimizing, or do I need to store it directly in the folder.

Comment: I think! I would say `move_uploaded_file()` to place it in a folder

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the help.